# unable to plot regression line in R with ggplot2 update1

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, regression

[image]These are part of the data and the code, I'd like to plot the regression with ggplot2 in R.
The result is undesirable, could you tell what mistakes that I made, please?

````
     age purchase_freq
   <dbl> <chr>        
 1    81 30           
 2    61 89           
 3    54 67           
 4    33 43           
 5    55 35           
 6    58 25           
 7    31 71           
 8    20 10           
 9    77 18           
10    45 23           
# … with 900 more rows```
````

```
ggplot(test1, aes(x = age, y = purchase_freq)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Comment: Hi James. Can you help us by clarifying what about the result is undesirable?

Comment: There are no mistakes in the code, maybe it's the wrong model?

Comment: Sorry, I did not succeed uploading the result, I have uploaded @JasonPunyon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`purchase_freq` is a `character` in your data frame, which means its y-values are discrete which is messing things up. Convert it to a number using `as.numeric` and things ought to get better.